# Tibco - Compare values activity

Tags: tibco

Let's say I have a value that is passed to a process. What activity should i use to compare this value with another?

I know it may seem a foolish question, but i am new to this.

Comment: It depends on your purpose. You want to compare the values so that... What?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about BusinessWorks, comparing text values of XML attributes or elements is done with XPath using the '=' sign. You don't need to use any specific activity to do so. This can actually be done on any branch (with the "Success with condition" switch) or on the input tab of any activity.

For instance, if you want to compare the text values of 2 elements, you can use an XPath formula like this:

```
$Start/root/myString1 = $Start/root/myString2
```

This formula returns `true` if `myString1` and `myString2` have the same text value, `false` otherwise.

Then you can, for example, use this formula as a test condition for an "If" or a "Choice" statement on an input tab of any activity.